# How do I prevent "This site is trying to download multiple files" on android phones?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a post-event site which allows delegates to download pdfs/images/videos from the event they have just visited. The problem, I am facing is that on android, when you visit the site, everything is downloading at once.

It is quite a simple site, and it downloads from a local folder through a tags.

Anyone know why this is? It happens only with android devices, doesn't happen with ios?

Many thanks.